# Temporary table in SQL Server - error occurs if the query takes long time to complete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have a look a the following query.

```
select * 
into TempTable
from MainTable

select * from TempTable
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'

drop table TempTable
```

After executing this query, I open other window and execute the query:

```
select * 
into TempTable
from MainTable

select * from TempTable

drop table TempTable
```

I get the following error:

> There is already an object named 'TempBucket' in the database.

Suppose that it a part of the stored procedure, and it takes a long time to finish. If there's a second call to this stored procedure, this error will occur. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Are you sure, that the second query starts after the first one is finished?

Comment: How is it "TempBucket" when you inserted into "TempTable"? For session based temp tables see the answer by @Drew R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using MSSQL DBMS by the tags against your post. 
Use a genuine temp table: prefix the name of the table with '#'.
Using this method the temp table will exist only in the scope of the procedure within which it was created.

```
select * 
into #TempTable
from MainTable

select * from #TempTable
```

No drop actually neccessary but is probably better practice.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#TempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #TempTable

SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM dbo.MainTable

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable
```

Comment: Devart - I upvoted. 
Just wondering why you would include the test for table existence & drop :)

Comment: IMHO, I think it's the best practice to do this.

Comment: Yes. Upvote for @Devart answer. This practice of checking the existence of temp table and dropping it before you create the one can prevent from accidental errors in many cases.

Comment: Agree. That's why Microsoft provided `DROP IF EXISTS` in SQL Server 2016.